# Bing xRank feed source

Tags: search, bing, bing-api

Is there any way I can get Bing xRank results ? Any RSS feeds, Bing API calls I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And to close the loop, xRank was recently shut down so that's one reason why it's not part of the Bing API.

See: http://searchengineland.com/official-bing-xrank-is-dead-52118

Answer (score 0):

There is a Bing PHP API that you can use :

http://bingphp.codeplex.com/